# Как отключить липкий скролл у строк кода в VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

При прокрутке кода в VS Code, сверху остаются строки, которые я уже пролистнул. В чем может заключаться проблема?

[image: Как выглядит сама проблема]

Comment: В настройках где-то должна быть стыковка строк по структуре. Отключите его.

Comment: on english stackoverflow, see [VS Code 1.86 line of code started following me in split at top of screen as I scroll. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77768982/11107541)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Нажмите `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P`
2. Напишите `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`
3. Найдите в открывшемся файле `"editor.stickyScroll.enabled": true`
4. Замените на `false` или просто удалите строку.

Answer (score 0):

Настройки - Параметры. Набрать в Параметры (Sticky Scroll).
В открывшемся окне найти Editor > Sticky Scroll: Enabled и убрать галочку.